# Facebook API - Get all latest comments and post without specifying post id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch all the comments from last 5 hours, also this data includes the User data who has commented, time and post id.

I checked the official API call but need to define the post id

```
[post_id]/comments
```

Also checked the comments API, it is also asking for object id

```
{object-id}/comments
```

Is there any way to fetch all latest comments made on the page?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your response. Is it possible to get the latest posts to which user interacted?

Comment: No, that is not possible either.

Comment: Maybe webhooks could help here though, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks - I think subscribing to changes of a page’s feed, includes comments made by users. So Facebook would notify your app when new comments are made, and you could record them on your end, so that you can select those from the last five hours from that data set on your end then.

Comment: Really appreciated. Thanks for the help